# Are there certain pages that shouldn't be included in ui-router scheme?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` in my Angular project.

I'm wondering, is it wise to include the whole project in the `ui-router` scheme or will there be performance, security, etc issues?

Just for illustration, my application is an online graphics editing program with a main page that contains the flagship app, but supported with pages such as "My Projects", "My Profile", "Projects Overview", "Statistics" etc.

I'm thinking that since the main page is so heavy, maybe it shouldn't be included in `ui-router`.

Honestly, I don't know much about the topic, but I'd rather get some well seasoned opinions before investing time either way.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

No,you can add all pages in ui-router and you should,that is the basic purpose of single page application that angular should handle all the routing part,i don't think there will be any performance issue because it will only get loaded when required.